# Filtering based on two conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

I have eight cards with two parameters on each of them. The first parameter  is year (2011, 2012, 2013, 2014), the second is category (studio, house, personal, commercial). It looks like this:

- Studio 2011
- House 2012
- Commercial 2013
- Personal 2012
- Studio 2014
- Commercial 2011
- House 2014
- Personal 2013

I need to sort them out, making needed cards bright, and not needed faded. By default all of them are bright. HTML:

```
<div class="card card-studio card-2011 card-bright">Studio 2011</div>
<div class="card card-house card-2012 card-bright">House 2012</div>
<div class="card card-commercial card-2013 card-bright">Commercial 2013</div>
<div class="card card-personal card-2012 card-bright">Personal 2012</div>
<div class="card card-studio card-2014 card-bright">Studio 2014</div>
<div class="card card-commercial card-2011 card-bright">Commercial 2011</div>
<div class="card card-house card-2014 card-bright">House 2014 </div>
<div class="card card-personal card-2013 card-bright">Personal 2013</div>
```

I add buttons with years:

```
<a href="#" class="button button-2011">2011</a>
<a href="#" class="button button-2012">2012</a>
<a href="#" class="button button-2013">2013</a>
<a href="#" class="button button-2014">2014</a>
```

When user clicks a year button, we take cards with needed year class and remove their "bright/faded" classes just in case. Then we add "bright" class to these cards. Then we take all the cards that do not have needed year and add them "faded" class (also removing previous classes just in case). And we also make the button underlined, and its siblings not underlined. It all looks like this:

```
$(".button").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass("button-2011")){
        $(".card-2011").removeClass("card-bright card-faded").addClass("card-bright");
        $(".card").not(".card-2011").removeClass("card-bright card-faded").addClass("card-faded");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("button-active").end().addClass("button-active");
}
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6vLzyowc/

Now it all seems simple, but trouble comes up when I try to add the second sorting condition, category.

On the one hand, I certainly need to do the same thing, as in the first case, i. e. make needed category bright, not needed faded:

```
if($(this).hasClass("button-house")){
        $(".card-house").removeClass("card-bright card-faded").addClass("card-bright");
        $(".card").not(".card-house").removeClass("card-bright card-faded").addClass("card-faded");
}
```

But it will make "bright" all cards with the needed category, and I also have the previous year sorting results. It seems that I need to sort them out first. So, I take the first year sorting results (i. e. "bright" cards) and make ones without needed category "faded":

```
if($(this).hasClass("button-house")){
        $(".card-bright").not("card-house").addClass("card-faded");
}
```

It helps a little, but I still don't know how I can add the remaining cards with needed category now, so that both conditions are satisfied. So, how can I combine **sorting previous sorting results** and **sorting all the items**?

Fiddle with all the buttons: https://jsfiddle.net/hm1emr8p/

Comment: Your use of the word "sort" is confusing; is there really any actual sorting (reordering) going on?

Comment: I think they mean "filter".

Comment: Reinventing rabio buttons.

Comment: I just need the same behaviour, as in the first fiddle, but with two conditions. No reordering.

Comment: I answered but forgot something, I am working on it and will report back :)

Comment: Ok, my answer and fiddle are up. Let me know if it is of use to you, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is a bit over-complicated. The following works for any number of filters. The trick is to keep state of what is selected, and on any change just re-apply this state to the card-elements.

```js
(function () {
  var active = [];

  $('.filter').each(function (idx, el) {
    var $el = $(el);

    active.push('');

    $el.on('click', '.button', function () {
      var $this = $(this);

      active[idx] = $this.data('toggle');

      $el.find('.button').removeClass('button-active');
      $this.addClass('button-active');

      update();
    });
  });

  function update()
  {
    var a = active.join('');

    if (a.length === 0) {
      $('.card').removeClass('card-faded');
    }
    else {
      $('.card').addClass('card-faded').filter(active.join('')).removeClass('card-faded');
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.time {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card-faded {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.button-active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="card card-2011 card-studio">Studio 2011</div>
<div class="card card-2012 card-house">House 2012</div>
<div class="card card-2013 card-commercial">Commercial 2013</div>
<div class="card card-2012 card-personal">Personal 2012</div>
<div class="card card-2014 card-studio">Studio 2014</div>
<div class="card card-2011 card-commercial">Commercial 2011</div>
<div class="card card-2014 card-house">House 2014 </div>
<div class="card card-2013 card-personal">Personal 2013</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <div class="filter time">
    <a class="button button-2011" data-toggle=".card-2011">2011</a>
    <a class="button button-2012" data-toggle=".card-2012">2012</a>
    <a class="button button-2013" data-toggle=".card-2013">2013</a>
    <a class="button button-2014" data-toggle=".card-2014">2014</a>
    <a class="button button-all button-active" data-toggle="">All time</a>
  </div>

  <div class="filter category">
    <a class="button button-studio" data-toggle=".card-studio">Studio</a>
    <a class="button button-house" data-toggle=".card-house">House</a>
    <a class="button button-commercial" data-toggle=".card-commercial">Commercial</a>
    <a class="button button-personal" data-toggle=".card-personal">Personal</a>
    <a class="button button-all button-active" data-toggle="">All</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! How can I get those 'run code snippet' and 'copy snippet to answer' buttons?

Comment: @TobiasBeuving There's a little `<>` button on the toolbar.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand much here. It seems that el stands for a button. But why do we push a '' in an empty array?

Comment: @qtxt `$el` is not the button, but rather the button-wrapping div. So in a sense, it's one of multiple filters (e.g. `time` and `category`). The empty string pushed to the array is used to ensure that for each filter we have an element at the same index in our state-array. This way we can later savely store active filters at the appropiate index (`active[idx] = $this.data('toggle');`). This way `active` always represents the current state. This is then used in `update` to reset (`removeClass`) all card-elements and then apply (`addClass('.card-faded')`) to the inverse selection.

Comment: I managed to figure out how it all works, but I don't get one thing. When you start learning JS/Jquery, they usually show something like function(X), where X is some prompt provided by user, with the final output looking like "Hello " + X. It all seems clear. But here, how does it get to know that idx and el are what they are?

Comment: @qtxt Thats just *api*. Have a look at the documenation provided by jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest saving the selected category and the selected timespan in variables:

```
var lastCategory = '';
var lastYear = '';
```

In your case you can use `data-` attributes to store information like this:

```
<a href="#" data-year="2011" class="button button-2011">2011</a>
```

and:

```
<a href="#" data-cat="studio" class="button button-studio">Studio</a>
```

And perform actions based on the value of the data element in your `click` handler:

```
$(".category > .button").on("click", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var tmpCat = $(this).data('cat');
    lastCategory = tmpCat;
    $(".card").removeClass("card-faded");


    if (tmpCat == 'all') {
        if (lastYear == 'alltime') {
            $(".card").addClass("card-faded");
        } else {
            $(".card-"+lastYear).addClass("card-faded");
        }

    } else {

        if (lastYear == 'alltime') {
            $(".card-" + tmpCat).addClass("card-faded");
        } else {
            $(".card-" + tmpCat + ".card-"+lastYear).addClass("card-faded");
        }

    }


     $(this).siblings()
            .removeClass("button-active")
            .end()
            .addClass("button-active");        



});

$(".time > .button").on("click", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var tmpYear = $(this).data('year');
    lastYear = tmpYear;
    $(".card").removeClass("card-faded");

   if (tmpYear == 'alltime') {

        if (lastCategory == 'all') {
            $(".card").addClass("card-faded");
        } else {
            $(".card-" + lastCategory).addClass("card-faded");
        }

    } else {
        if (lastCategory == 'all') {
            $(".card-" + tmpYear).addClass("card-faded");
        } else {
            $(".card-" + lastCategory + ".card-"+tmpYear).addClass("card-faded");
        }

    }        



     $(this).siblings()
            .removeClass("button-active")
            .end()
            .addClass("button-active");        

});
```

There a zillion ways that lead to rome, this is not ideal, but try to avoid `if (1) then, if (2) then, if (3) then, etc....` code. I forked [your fiddle and made a working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tobiasbeuving/ecyao6pL/6/).

Comment: Thanks, I managed to modify it a little, so it acts according to my initial purpose: https://jsfiddle.net/r114zcqp/1/

Comment: Great! Glad I could help and good luck with your project! Cheers